# Why is my fast refresh for Next.js acting like this?

Tags: next.js

The problem:

1. I run `npx next dev`
2. I edit some text within a div and save
3. Fast refresh reloads the page to show the changes an everything works
4. I go back and change the text again and save
5. Fast refresh shows activity in the terminal, but the changes don't appear in the browser
6. I manually reload the page in the browser and I'm met with 3 errors

`Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.`

`Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

`Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering`

To get it to load, I have to stop the dev, and rerun `npx next dev`

I'm brand new to Next.js; however, I seem to understand that there's a mismatch between the client and the server, but every time I wan't to edit any text, I have to restart? This doesn't seem right

[image]

```
const style = {
  wrapper: `relative`,
  container: `before:content-[''] before:bg-red-500 before:absolute before:top-0 before:left-0 before:right-0 before:bottom-0 before:bg-[url('https://psychedelicsanonymous.com/_next/static/images/hd-genesis-bg-1a3c22850acd321ed3b63ab12dd2c2b0.jpg')] before:bg-cover before:bg-center before:opacity-30 before:blur`,
  contentWrapper: `flex h-screen relative justify-center flex-wrap items-center`,
  copyContainer: `w-1/2`,
  title: `relative text-white text-[46px] font-semibold`,
  description: `text-[#8a939b] container-[400px] text-2xl mt-[0.8rem] mb-[2.5rem]`,
  ctaContainer: `flex`,
  accentedButton: ` relative text-lg font-semibold px-12 py-4 bg-[#2181e2] rounded-lg mr-5 text-white hover:bg-[#42a0ff] cursor-pointer`,
  button: ` relative text-lg font-semibold px-12 py-4 bg-[#363840] rounded-lg mr-5 text-[#e4e8ea] hover:bg-[#4c505c] cursor-pointer`,
  cardContainer: `rounded-[4rem]`,
  infoContainer: `h-20 bg-[#313338] p-4 rounded-b-lg flex items-center text-white`,
  author: `flex flex-col justify-center ml-4`,
  name: ``,
  infoIcon: `flex justify-end items-center flex-1 text-[#8a939b] text-3xl font-bold`
};

const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <div className={style.wrapper}>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <div className={style.contentWrapper}>
          <div className={style.copyContainer}>
            <div className={style.title}>
              This is where I try to edit the text
            </div>
            <div className={style.description}>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam
            </div>
            <div className={style.ctaContainer}>
              <button className={style.accentedButton}>Explore</button>
              <button className={style.button}>Create</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={style.cardContainer}>
            <img
              className="rounded-t-lg"
              src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ujepnqpnL0nDQIHsWxlCXzyw4pf01yjz1Jmb4kAQHumJAPrSEj0-e3ABMZlZ1HEpJoqwOcY_kgnuJGzfXbd2Tijri66GXUtfN2MXQA=s550"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```